# pg_upgradecluster fails with "Error: could not get cluster locales"

Tags: postgresql, database, perl, postgresql-cluster

I'm trying to upgrade postgres cluster from 9.5 to 10

Steps I did:

- installed postgresql-10 and postgresql-client-10
- removed new default 10 main cluster
- used command "**pg_upgradecluster 9.5 main**" which resulted in **"Error: could not get cluster locales"**

my 9.5 locale settings are:

```
postgres=# SHOW LC_CTYPE;
  lc_ctype  
------------
 et_EE.UTF8
(1 row)

postgres=# SHOW LC_COLLATE;
 lc_collate 
------------
 et_EE.UTF8
(1 row)
```

system locales:

```
root@server:~# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
et_EE.utf8
POSIX

root@server:~# locale
LANG=et_EE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=et_EE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="et_EE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="et_EE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="et_EE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="et_EE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="et_EE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="et_EE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="et_EE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="et_EE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="et_EE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="et_EE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="et_EE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="et_EE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=et_EE.UTF-8
```

postgres.conf:

```
# These settings are initialized by initdb, but they can be changed.
lc_messages = 'et_EE.UTF8'                      # locale for system error message
                                        # strings
lc_monetary = 'et_EE.UTF8'                      # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'et_EE.UTF8'                       # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'et_EE.UTF8'                          # locale for time formatting
```

Has anyone else run into trouble with pg_upgradecluster?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Postgresql thread [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CABnTomKNDj%2BorMgyPaPtFkNoBFCuSWnzSAd0X0%2BX4LHSgUbEDQ%40mail.gmail.com) that suggests running the `pg_upgradecluster` command as `root` could help because:

> [...] sometimes, in Ubuntu systems, if ssh login user's locale is different, it ["Error: could not get cluster locales"] may happen.

I don't know if you are on a Ubuntu system, but maybe you could give it a try?